How to save a debug trace of an application that hangs/crashes the OS/PC?
Rationale

For this AMD GPU driver bug of mine, I want to capture a (stack/back)trace of the Prism Launcher Flatpak package. [1] However, as the afore-referenced bug explains, the issue experienced crashes my OS. In order for the report to be more actionable, I want to capture a trace.
To accomplish this, I have installed the Freedesktop, GNOME, and KDE debug SDKs, and gdb. I've got as far as running gdb inside the Flatpak container, but I need to type bt in order to save the trace.
Request

Consequently, how can I capture and automatically save a trace the moment that it occurs, so that I can shut down my PC whilst ensuring that the data is captured?
Caveats

Unfortunately, numerable things are unavailable to me (most of the time - the symptoms of the issue do, rarely, positively differ, but I cannot count on that):

I cannot (usually) switch TTYs when it occurs.
The SysReq commands do not always function. It's a 20% chance.

However, a solution which ignores these caveats remains a useful solution.
